# Ajax success and error message html problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I found nothing due to this concrete problem. I am trying to display a message within a different div depending on the responsetext of my ajax request. I created two divs #uploadResponsesuccess and #uploadResponseerror. But because the divs are already created before submitting the ajax request, both divs show up before it is getting modified by the ajax function.

Possible to "hide" them before ajax got a response and modified them? Otherwise they just show up without submitting. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVJW2.png)

```
$(function() {

    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://example/post.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (response === "success") {
                    $("#uploadResponsesuccess").html(response);

                } else if (response === "error") {
                    $("#uploadResponseerror").html(response);
                }
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="uploadResponsesuccess"></div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="uploadResponseerror"></div>
```

Comment: While you can certainly solve the problem you are asking about, why not use only one `div` for your messages and just add the appropriate class depending on whether you get a success or error response?

Comment: @benvc I already tried to update the class of a div, but no success on it.

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/addClass/,https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ ,https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: You might want to have a look at [jQuery Hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [jQuery Show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/). You can also use [jQuery addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [jQuery removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) like @benvc said.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide them from load by adding `style="display:none;"` to the divs, and then show the appropriate one after the ajax call finishes:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="uploadResponsesuccess" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="uploadResponseerror" style="display:none;"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    // hide any alerts that might already be showing
    $("#uploadResponsesuccess").hide();
    $("#uploadResponseerror").hide();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://example/post.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (response === "success") {
                $("#uploadResponsesuccess").html(response).show();

            } else if (response === "error") {
                $("#uploadResponseerror").html(response).show();
            }
        }
    });

});
```